# urgent: missing pages iv and v

Tags: page-numbering

[image] I have a strange thing which is that my thesis is missing the page numbers iv and v. I need to get it fixed to be able to submit my thesis. Can someone help? What is the command that controls page numbers in LaTeX?

here is the frontpages file for my thesis in Latex.

```
% TITLE PAGE 
% By Stephen Carr and Wail Gueaieb
% Updated 2005-04-07

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers or page numbers

\begin{center}

\vspace*{1.0cm}
{\bf \LARGE %
  \thesistitlecoverpage}

\vspace*{1.0cm}
\normalsize
by \\
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\Large
\thesisauthor\\
\vspace*{2.0cm}
\normalsize
Thesis submitted to the\\
Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Studies\\
In partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
For the \degree~degree in\\
\nameofprogram\\

\vspace*{2.0cm}
\academicunit\\
\faculty\\
University of Ottawa\\

\vspace*{2.0cm}
\copyright~\thesisauthor, Ottawa, Canada, \graduationyear\\

\end{center}

\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% PRELIMINARY PAGES
\pagestyle{plain} % No headers, just page numbers
\pagenumbering{roman} % Roman numerals
\setcounter{page}{2}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% This page is not needed for the University of Ottawa
% % Declaration Page
% \noindent
% I hereby declare that I am the sole author of this thesis.

% \noindent
% I authorize the University of Ottawa to lend this thesis to other
% institutions or individuals for the purpose of scholarly research.
% \vspace{4cm}

% \noindent
% \thesisauthor

% \vspace{4cm}

% \noindent
% I further authorize the University of Ottawa to reproduce this thesis by
% photocopying or other means, in total or in part, at the request of other
% institutions or individuals for the purpose of scholarly research.
% \vspace{4cm}

% \noindent
% \thesisauthor
% \newpage
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

% Long abstract (manually formatted)
\begin{center}
\Large
\textbf{Abstract}
\end{center}
\input{\abstractfile}
\newpage

% Acknowledgements and/or Dedication Pages
\begin{center}\textbf{Acknowledgements}\end{center}
\input{\acknowledgementfile}
\newpage

% Pages which are generated automatically
\setcounter{page}{6} % Set this counter to get correct page numbers
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\printnomenclature
\newpage

% Change page numbering back to Arabic numerals
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

thanks,

Comment: You can find the cause using [a very simple mechanical algorithm](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/). If the cause in the reduced code is not obvious for you, it will be for one of us.

Comment: Remove `\setcounter{page}{6}`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the command that controls page numbers in LaTeX?

- The *value* of the page number is controlled via

  ```
  \setcounter{page}{<some number>}
  ```

  E.g., `\setcounter{page}{10}`
- The *style* of the page number display -- arabic numerals, lowercase or uppercase Roman numerals, etc -- is controlled via

  ```
   \pagenumbering{<some style>}
  ```

  where valid options for `<some style>` provided by the LaTeX kernel are `arabic`, `roman`, `Roman`, `alph`, and `Alph`.

In the case of the code you've posted, you should delete the instruction `\setcounter{page}{6}` so as not to skip over pages `iv` and `v`.